# How to read multiple files from within awk script without passing at command line?

Tags: awk

I have an awk script which is called something like this:

```
awk -f d.awk /var/log/app*.log
```

And this works fine. Log file path is constant and not changing (only the number of files changes in this location due to log rotation) so I want to remove it from command line and hard code inside the awk script. 
Is there a way to skip passing this argument from command line and hard code it within the awk script and still achieve the same result?

I read about getline but it is not working for me.
awk script outline is something like this:

```
BEGIN{
    #Initialization of few variable
}
match() {
    #Main process logic
    # Collect the output
    output=output" " result_after_processing
}
END{
    #Write the output to output file
    print output >> some_output_file
}
```

Comment: Why?  Seems to me you want to work the other direction.  Instead of `awk -f`, write a shell script which embeds the awk and uses `/var/log/app*.log` as arguments.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks for your reply. I thought of that but I need to call this awk from an existing C code and don't want to (or allowed to) add another layer in between. Problem is existing C code is very bad in parsing wild card (*) and producing some weird results. I don't have access to existing C code. Hence thought of getting rid of this argument.

Comment: The log file path is processed by the shell to give a list of filenames for `awk` to work on, you can't control that with `awk`

Comment: @Inian This link talks about getline to read from a file within awk script. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fFile

Comment: You can use `getline < "filename"` to read file a file, but it won't expand wildcards, and I don't think there's a way to reassign awk's input to another file in general.

Comment: @Inian, yes, you can, but it's ugly - you can populate awk's ```ARGC/ARGV``` based on your own scanning of a dir for files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BEGIN {
    cmd = "printf \047%s\n\047 /var/log/app*.log"
    while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        ARGV[ARGC++] = line
    }
    close(cmd)
}
```

should work as long as your file names don't contain newlines.

This is one of those rare cases where use of getline is appropriate - make sure to read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're ever considering using it in future.